# Small but important edits -- what do we do?

Tags: discussion

I just found a broken URL--a one-character fix.  I can't edit it, because edits must be at least 6 characters.

What's the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Why can't you edit it?

Comment: Then you can add hidden charchters, add some html tags or spaces and write on the explanation that they are there to add to the char count.

Answer (score 1):

Edit it (if able) or ask the OP to edit it.

Comment: Every user can at least suggest an edit, it's better than asking the OP

Answer (score 1):

The original developers of the Stack Exchange software wanted edits to be easy, so people could improve the content, but found that people were using it to make absolutely trivial edits - correcting the spelling of one word was thought to be too trivial to trigger all the actions that occur when an edit/proposed edit is made (notifying the author, pushing it to the top of the active questions, adding to review lists, etc.).

They added a rule in the software that no single character changes can be made, to avoid trivial spelling edits.

Now, I think we can all agree that an edit to fix a URL so it is not broken is a more important edit than fixing a "lose/loose" spelling confusion. Even though there is an unthinking software rule proscribing it, it is an edit that is worth the effort, and we should appreciate the fix.

I think this warrants us looking the other way while you workaround the limitations of the software. Make the one character change, and then make some other trivial/invisible change to defeat the character count limit.

If it is a genuine attempt to improve the content, and not merely to cheat the original intention of the rule, I am sure everyone will be thankful.

Comment: HTML comments are one technique.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you're going to have to cheat the system, you can add a comment in HTML anywhere in the edit which will make it invisible, for example just add this anywhere:

```
<!-- This is an invisible comment -->
```

You can also, edit other sentences in the answer, keep searching until you find something useful to improve and fix. This will bypass the 6-character rule.

Moreover, if you want to see a demonstration of how it looks like, here is the source of this [answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/ccb4ec54-0148-4cd9-8989-283168133ca3/view-source).